# Configure NancyFx with Fluent Validation

Tags: configuration, fluentvalidation, nancy

Is there any configuration code that I have to add in the application Bootstrapper to enable FluentValidation in Nancy?

Following the example from https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Validation I receive the following exception message when trying to use this.Validate on model: **No model validator factory could be located**.

I'm using Nancy version 0.11.0.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using one of the Bootstrapper packages (autofac, ninject, unity, windsor, structuremap)? If you are then you need to inherit from the bootstrapper type, override ConfigureApplicationContainer and register the type in the container. If you are using the default bootstrapper then it should wire itself up

With out next release, 0.12, it will wired up automatically no matter what bootstrapper you are using

Comment: Yes, my application Bootstrapper inherits NinjectNancyBootstrapper.

I have registered DefaultFluentAdapterFactory for IFluentAdapterFactory and FluentValidationValidatorFactory for IModelValidatorFactory and it works.

Should any of this two be registered as singletons?

Comment: Yeah singleton is fine. Nancy is designed to be stateless