# Wiring up fluentvalidation with Nancy and Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, nancy, fluentvalidation

I am using Nancy with Ninject as IoC. All is fine. I now need to add FluentValidation. 
How do I go about wiring Nancy to use FluentValidation via Ninject?

I see there's a NuGet package [Ninject.Fluent.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation/) but I can't find any documentation or example on how to use it.

The demo project on NancyFx website uses the TinyIoC so it's not useful to me.

**UPDATE**: this is what I have tried to do:

```
var createRequest = this.BindAndValidate<CreateRequest>();

if (!ModelValidationResult.IsValid)
{
    return Response.AsJson(ModelValidationResult, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);    
}
```

The model is always valid (even if there should be errors reported by the `CreateConsumerRequestValidator`).

This is what I have added in my Ninject bootstrapper:

```
Bind<IModelValidatorFactory>().To<FluentValidationValidatorFactory>().InSingletonScope();

AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<CreateRequestValidator>()
.ForEach(match => Bind(match.InterfaceType).To(match.ValidatorType));
```

Answer (score 0):

The IModelValidatorFactory is wired up automatically by Nancy from v0.12 (see here [Configure NancyFx with Fluent Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178201/configure-nancyfx-with-fluent-validation)) - you just need to wire up your validators.

This works with Nancy 0.23

```
using FluentValidation;

using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Ninject.Modules;

public class ValidatorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Kernel.Bind(
            x =>
            x.FromAssembliesMatching("YourNameSpace.*")
             .SelectAllClasses()
             .InheritedFrom<IValidator>()
             .BindAllInterfaces());
    }
}
```