# Nancyfx, Ninject and Fluent Validation

Tags: ninject, nancy, fluentvalidation

i am using Nancyfx, Ninject and FluentValidation to server a angularjs powered website. Everything worked fine, until i added a fluent-validation.

Here is (the in my opinion) important code:

```
public class WebServerModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IModelValidatorFactory>().To<FluentValidationValidatorFactory>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(p => p.UserNumber).NotEmpty();
    }
}

protected virtual dynamic HandlePost(dynamic parameters) {
    try {
        TEntity e = this.BindAndValidate<TEntity>();
        var table = TableForType<TEntity>();
        table.Insert(e);

        return HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
}
```

Everytime i call post on my angular-side an System.ArgumentException is thrown on the line: 
"TEntity e = this.BindAndValidate();"
The Message Text is: "An item with the same key has already been added."

Could you please lend me a hand with this problem?

Best regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

The IModelValidatorFactory is wired up automatically by Nancy from v0.12 (see here [Configure NancyFx with Fluent Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178201/configure-nancyfx-with-fluent-validation)) - you just need to wire up your validators.

This works with Nancy 0.23

```
using FluentValidation;

using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Ninject.Modules;

public class ValidatorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Kernel.Bind(
            x =>
            x.FromAssembliesMatching("YourNameSpace.*")
             .SelectAllClasses()
             .InheritedFrom<IValidator>()
             .BindAllInterfaces());
    }
}
```